# Android, GTE Cybertrust Root and the Keystore

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

Im seeing some strangeness with the GTE CyberTrust Global Root on android 2.1 and 2.2.

If i add the cert using the CertificateInstaller from a WebView it claims the cert is a 'user certificate' and puts it in the user store:

From the [android source](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiDialog.java.html) i can see:
cert location = KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.USER_CERTIFICATE

If i add a self signed CA cert it adds it to the correct store:
cert location = KEYSTORE_SPACE + Credentials.CA_CERTIFICATE

So, im using ca_cert from wifiManager for EAP wireless auth [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java#WifiConfiguration.0ca_cert):

public EnterpriseField ca_cert = new EnterpriseField("ca_cert");

If i set it to "keystore://CACERT_gteCert" it fails.

If i set it to "keystore://USRCERT_getCert" is works.

Any ideas on this behavior?

Its going to make programming a wpa_supplicant configuration app for non rooted devices difficult. Im hoping i misunderstand something?